# use character from latex package in rmarkdown with html_output

Tags: latex, r-markdown

I'm trying to use symbols from a latex package loaded in the yaml preamble (e.g. musicography in this example). It works with output set to pdf, but not with hmtl output. How can I access commands/symbols from the loaded package with output set to html_document?

```
---
title: test
output:
  html_document
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{musicography}
---
  
$\musHalf$
```

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** Not all Latex packages will work with `output: html_document`. Quoting user cderv [here](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1829#issuecomment-636445114):
*You need to see if MathJax support the Tex package as an extension*

---

[This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/25672/627667) answer on Mathematics Meta SE suggests a workaround using Unicode characters, if you find the corresponding one.
For a complete list of musical symbols, see [the Unicode Standard, Version 13.0](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1D100.pdf). Once you have the Unicode, you next need the *HTML Entity*. Finally, place the HTML Entity in the document and knit.

From your example, I think you are trying to represent a *half note*, for which I found the Unicode to be `1D15E`. The corresponding *HTML Entities* are `&#119134;` and `&#x1D15E;` which I found [here](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+1D15E):

[image]

The code would be:

```
---
title: test
output:
  html_document
---

&#119134;  
&#x1D15E;
```

Finally, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Music) Wikipedia entry offers links to [Western Musical Symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_Symbols_(Unicode_block)), [Byzantine Musical Symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byzantine_Musical_Symbols) and [Ancient Greek Musical Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Greek_Musical_Notation), in case you need any of these.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that as well, but these  unicode characters are rendered for me as two empty squares (in chrome)--do I need to set the character encoding or change the font of the page? 

But also, my question was more general: I would like to use character from latex packages in my html code (I also compile to pdf. and use latex code to generate the special symbols there). Is there a way to do this? Or is the reason that this doesn't work with musicography package something about this package?

Comment: For the first question it seems to be a font issue; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23141285/10152848). For the second please see my edit (I added it to the answer since I think it better suits there).